# Probability that points are on a straight line

Tags: probability, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am looking at a formula to calculate the probability that $n$ points are on a straight line between point $1$ and point $n$ in 2d Euclidean space.

If the points are exactly on the line, the probability should be $1$, and I guess if point #$1$ is $(0,0)$ and point $n$ is $(m, m)$ then if the points are on the line $(0,0; 0,m)$ and $(0,m; m,m)$ then the probability would be $0$.

I can calculate the distance to the line between $(0,0)$ and $(m,m)$ but how can I use that as a measure? This would be very dependent on the length of the line and the amount of points.

If somebody could point me in the right direction that would be great :)

Thanks

Comment: If the coordinates are chosen from $\mathbb R$, the probability under any reasonable distribution is zero.  If they are chosen from $\Bbb Z$ you need to specify the range of integers that you consider, or what probability distribution you are using.

Comment: Your question sounds like you don't actually want to compute a probability, but are instead looking for measure for the *colinearity* of $n$ points. In other words, for some function of $n$ points that yields $1$ if they're colinear, $0$ if they're, say, the edges of a regular polygon, and something in between otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to fgp I found my answer; when googling collinearity measure I found on wikipedia correlation, which makes perfect sense :)

If the points are on a straight line, the abs(correlation) will be 1 and if there is a large curve between points, it will be close to 0 which is exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks for you help and describing in good way what I was looking for :)